# Is it possible to increase chrome.bookmarks.MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried setting the property to a much higher value but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how I should go about it? (It's for an extension which allows you to switch between multiple bookmark bars.)

Documentation's here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html

EDIT: Below's the source code.

```
(function(){
    function f(d) {
        chrome.bookmarks.MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR = 100000000;
        chrome.bookmarks.MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE = 2000000;
        chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(tree) {
            if (!searchFolder(tree[0], "Switchmark")) {
                chrome.bookmarks.create({"title": "Switchmark"}, function(n){
                    chrome.bookmarks.create({"title": "A", parentId: n.id});
                    chrome.bookmarks.create({"title": "B", parentId: n.id});
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text": "A"});
                });
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    if (!children[i].children.length) {
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text": children[i].title});
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(f);
    chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(f);
}).call();

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(t) {
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(tree) {
        var children = searchFolder(tree[0], "Switchmark").children;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (!children[i].children.length) {
                var barId = searchFolder(tree[0], "Bookmarks bar").id;
                var currentId = children[i].id;
                var nextNode = children[++i < children.length ? i : 0];
                var nextId = nextNode.id;
                var nextTitle = nextNode.title;
                moveFolderContents(barId, currentId);
                moveFolderContents(nextId, barId);
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text": nextTitle});
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});

function moveFolderContents(fromId, toId) {
    chrome.bookmarks.getSubTree(fromId, function (subtree) {
        var c = subtree[0].children;
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) chrome.bookmarks.move(c[i].id, {"parentId": toId});
    });
}

function searchFolder(n, f) {
    if (Array.isArray(n.children)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < n.children.length; i++) {
            if (n.children[i].title == f) return n.children[i];
            else if (r = searchFolder(n.children[i], f)) return r;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Why aren't you just using [`chrome.bookmarks.move`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#method-move) between folders to the bookmark bar?

Comment: I do use chrome.bookmarks.move in the extension, but it stops working after a certain number of times (which I presume is the default value). I'll upload the source once I get back home.

Comment: Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switchmark/bnocffbiglfjjcgmifcampfmcbkfbhgc

Source: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dbnocffbiglfjjcgmifcampfmcbkfbhgc%26uc (crx file, can be unzipped)

Comment: I will look at the sources, but I'm not very optimistic about going past the max-writes limit. You could put the sources on github :)

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/Alesix/Switchmark12

Comment: From what I see so far, it seems to me that the property is read-only although setting a value doesn't trigger any error.

Comment: Yup, seems to be the same way to me. I doubt there is a straightforward way to do this, considering not more than 2 move operations are allowed over 10 mins. But there might be a `chrome://flags` way. Not sure. Will play around with it a bit.

Comment: Something similar [**here**](https://github.com/Codegasm/Bookmark-Bar-Switcher/blob/master/background.js). The author mentions similar limitations of this idea. looks like there isn't a way for now.

Comment: I guess it's something the Chromium devs would have to do something about. But anyway, thanks for taking the time to look through the issue!